# AngularJS Not Displaying Message Properly

Tags: .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner programmer learning angular and following along with a Music Store Application. I am having some trouble displaying a message in angularJS and was wondering if its a problem in the code, or something else. My expected result is to simply display "Manish Kumar" on the page. However, my actual result is simply displaying {{message}} from the html. It's as if its not picking up the JS controller reference. Please note the example was done in VS 2013, while I'm using 2015. Any help is appreciated, as I am a beginner. Thanks!!

My Code & Files:

Index HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="../../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/theMusic.js"></script> 
    <script src="../Scripts/MusicListController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="theMusic">
        <div ng-controller="MusicListController">
            {{message}}
        </div>  
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

MusicListController:

```
(function (app) {
    var MusicListController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Manish Kumar";
    };
    app.controller("MusicListController", MusicListController);
}(Angular.module("theMusic")));
```

theMusic Class:

```
(function () {
    var app = Angular.module("theMusic", []);
}());
```

Comment: Do you have any js errors in your browser console ?

Comment: Not sure.. but change `Angular` to `angular`..

Comment: I don't show any errors. Is it possibly how I am referencing the MusicListController? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, @developer033, that fixed it!! Thank you very much, those are the simple things us beginners stumble on!

Comment: It happens, glad that helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this type i think solve  your problem  just make some changes.

```js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("theMusic", []);
}());

(function (app) {
    var MusicListController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Manish Kumar";
    };
    app.controller("MusicListController", MusicListController);
}(angular.module("theMusic")));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="../../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/theMusic.js"></script> 
    <script src="../Scripts/MusicListController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="theMusic">
        <div ng-controller="MusicListController">
            {{message}}
        </div>  
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```